# If $f$ has derivative at $1$ and $\lim_{h \to 0} {\frac{f(1+h)}{h} }=1$, then $f'(1)=0=f(1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I need to prove that if $f(x)$ has derivative at $x=1$ and if $\lim_{h \to 0} {\frac{f(1+h)}{h} }=1$. then I need to prove that $f'(1)=0$ $f(1)=0$. It's pretty obovious if using arithmetic of limits, but it's impossible here. Any clues or general mindset how to prove it?

Comment: $$f'(1)=\lim_{h\to}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}h$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{f(1+h)}{h} = \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}+\frac{f(1)}{h}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{f(1)}{h} = \frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}.
$$
By assumption, the RHS goes to $1-f^\prime(1)$ when $h$ goes to $0$, but the LHS has no limit unless $f(1)=0$. Hence, $f(1)=0$, and you get by taking the limit $h\to 0$ on both sides that
$$
0 = 1 - f^\prime(1)
$$
i.e. $f^\prime(1)=1$.

Comment: I don't understand the part of "the LHS has no limit unless $f(1)=0$." I don't understand the other assumptions. I'd like to know more details about it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If $f(1)\neq 0$, the quantity $f(1)/h$ has no limit when $h\to 0$ ($f(1)/h$ goes to $\pm\infty$ depending on the sign of $f(1)$ and if $h\nearrow 0^-$  or $h\searrow 0^+$). The other assumptions are just that $f'(1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$ exists, and that $\frac{f(1+h)}{h}\to 1$ (i.e., the assumptions you wrote in the question).